# SAS - sgplot - setting transparency per group

Tags: graph, sas

In the example below, I would like to make the data from group 1 transparent (transparency= option) and to leave to data from group 2 as they are. Can you help me?

```
data dat;
    input group $ x y;
    datalines;
    1 0.5 2
    1 0.8 1
    1 1   2.2
    2 4.3 5
    2 0.7 2
    ;
run;

proc sgplot data=dat;
    scatter x=x y=y / markerattrs=(symbol=circlefilled size=8); 
run;
```

[image]

Comment: @akrun: sorry, incorrect handling... and now I cannot retrieve it and reopen it :-(

Comment: No problem, just for the future.  Somebody might benefit from keeping it open.

Comment: @akrun: Is there a way to reopen it?

Comment: You can click on the reopen button,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SAS 9.4 TS1M1 and later, this is possible by using an attribute map.

```
data dat;
    input group $ x y;
    datalines;
    1 0.5 2
    1 0.8 1
    1 1   2.2
    2 4.3 5
    2 0.7 2
    ;
run;

data group_attrmap;
    ID="groups";
    value=1;
    markercolor="cxFF0000";
    markertransparency=0.5;
    output;
    value=2;
    markertransparency=0;
    output;
run;

proc sgplot data=dat dattrmap=group_Attrmap;
    scatter x=x y=y / markerattrs=(symbol=circlefilled size=8) group=group attrid=groups;
run;
```

Before that, as `MARKERTRANSPARENCY` is not supported, your best bet is to have two separate plots - one for group 1, one for group 2, with separate transparencies.  You can do that by splitting x/y into two sets of columns, and for the other group that x/y are missing (then no dots are drawn).

You also could draw this with annotation, in this particular example, since annotating a scatter plot is simply a matter of setting up the right variables on the already existing dataset.